# Android Room - deleting from two entities using Transactions

Tags: android, android-room

How do i delete data from two tables in Android room using a transaction?  I cannot have data be deleted from just one table, its both or neither.  Both entities have 1 DAO each.

`TimerDesign` is parent, `IntervalDesign` is child

I have setup a parent - child class as i will need the 1:M relationship for this class later to get each parent with all its children, at present trying to delete one parent with all its children only deletes from the parent table.

```
public class FullTimerDesigns extends TimerDesign {
    @Embedded public TimerDesign timerDesign;

    @Relation(parentColumn = "timer_design_id", entityColumn = "parent_timer_id", entity = IntervalDesign.class)
    public List<IntervalDesign> intervalDesigns;
}
```

I need to spec the id of the parent to delete it and all its children.  I know my DAO `@Query` aren't specifying the child table, nor can i seem to do an inner join to solve this.

```
@Dao
public interface ParentWithChildDAO {
    @Transaction
    @Query("DELETE FROM parent WHERE parent_id = :id")
    public void deleteOneParentWithAllChildren(int id);

    @Transaction
    @Query("DELETE FROM parent")
    public void deleteAllParentsWithAllChildren();
}
```

Most examples and the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Transaction) i can find for the `Room` 1:m mapping class only show how to return everything from both tables, i cant find any information for deleting.

Comment: Where you define the foriegn parent key in the child entitiy relationship add `onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define a **ForeignKey** in the **IntervalDesigns** Entity the you can use  `onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE`. This will propagate deletion of the children when a parent is deleted and it's all done within the same transaction (so there would be no need for `@Transaction` on either of the queries).

- You can also specify onUpdate, however this would only propagate changes to the parent column (which is rarer).
- See [ForeignKey](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/ForeignKey#onDelete()) and perhaps also [SQLite ForeignKeySupport](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

Your code would be something like :-

```
@Entity(
    foreignKeys = {
        @ForeignKey(entity = TimerDesign.class,
        parentColumns = "timer_design_id",
        childColumns = "parent_timer_id",
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)
    },
    indices = {@Index("parent_timer_id")})

public class IntervalDesign {
    ... rest of the class/entity code
}
```

- Note the index has been added as otherwise Room issues a warning.
- Room will probably insist on updating the database schema version number next time you build the app.

---

**Alternative (not recommended)**

An Alternative albeit it a little clumsy would be to define Dao's for the deletion of each (children by parent_id and parent by it's id) and have a static method in the parent Entity (Timer_Design) that deletes the children and then the parent

- *this is the correct way as if a ForeignKey is defined to ensure referential integrity, but does not have the onDelete action defined, then an attempt to delete the parent will result in a ForeignKey conflict and fail.*

So you could have :-

```
@Query("DELETE FROM intervaldesign WHERE parent_timer_id=:parent_id")
int deleteItervalDesignChild(int parent_id);
@Query("DELETE FROM parent WHERE timer_design_id=:parent_id")
int deleteParent(int parent_id);
```

- *Note that your `@Query("DELETE FROM parent WHERE parent_id = :id")` appears to be incorrect as parent_id appears to be a column in the intervaldesign table (if that is its name).* The above assumes that the child table is named intervaldesign.

And in the TimerDesign class you could have :-

```
public static void deleteParentAndChildren(TheDatabase db, int parent_id) {
    db.runInTransaction(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            db.getAllDao().deleteItervalDesignChild(parent_id);
            db.getAllDao().deleteParent(parent_id);
        }
    });
}
```

- TheDatabase would be changed to you Room database class.
- The above is just for a single parent (Timer_Design). For all parents you could have additional DAO's to suit.

Comment: Thanks heaps for taking the time to answer that - your first answer worked.  How did i forget about good old cascade!!  No need for transactions either like you said.  I havent checked or tried the alternative answer.